# Prestashop add new item in Admin Panel Sidebar Menu

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I have small problem on create a custom item inside Admin Panel Sidebar Menu.

Prestashop Version: 1.7.4.2

This is the currently sidebar menu in my prestashop:

[image: Before Changes]

I would like to add new item that links to external website. As I have researched I found out that, this need to be a `controller` in order to be placed inside there as shown [here](https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/249135-how-to-create-new-tab-in-admin/).

As example shown above, they need to create a new controller for that specific purpose. What I need is a hardcoded fixed external url address, so in the end this would be the result:

[image: After Changes]

What I did is put paint inside the jpg that I had screenshot to illustrate my point. And when they clicked the text, it will redirect to `external page (not controller, etc)` like http://www.google.com.

Is there a Form that I can `hardcoded specific url` and show it so that user can redirect when needed.

Sorry as this is only concept no php code provided, as I didn't know how to accomplish it.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All items that are shown in the sidebar menu have to be an `AdminController class` and added in the `tab` of PrestaShop.

Then, in your AdminController, you make the redirection:

```
<?php

class AdminMyModuleRedirectController extends ModuleAdminController
{
    public function init()
    {
        Tools::redirect('https://www.google.com');
    }
}
```

You still can manually modify the template that shows the sidebar menu, but it's not recommended.

Good luck

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, where should i put the php file that only contains that code? I have tried put it in /classes folder. Where is the sidebar menu template that I can add new row

Answer (score 0):

You have two simple ways that don't needed to deep scan PrestaShop codes.

1- On your module => admin controller:

```
public function init()
{
    Tools::redirect('https://google.com');
}
```

2- on your module main php file:

-- add "back office header" hook

-- load jQuery file in this hook

-- change URL of your controller by jquery